# Creating a simple Matlab GUI, need some advice

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I'm thinking about creating a matlab GUI, which functionality is the following:

I have a function M=F(a,b,c) which output is a matrix M, and M can be plot in a 3D space.

Now I want to have one(or multiple) nob/bar for me to adjust the parameter "a"(or three nob/bars for a,b,c) . So the plot can draw it's output instantly.

Because my F might be a computational expensive function.

So i would like to pre-compute all the output corresponding to different parameters. then I would get no lag in my GUI.

Also because of the complexity, my nob/bar would be quite "discrete",i.e only 10 different values for one parameter.

But now I have completely no clue how to do this in MATLAB,
can anyone give me some direction for searching what matlab functions will i need?
(My confusion is on the GUI, how do I do the nob/bar things? or instant update things?)

or a better way to implement what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which part you have no clue how to do (GUI part or generating the data), but I will assume you are trying to find a way to nicely store your result matrices so you can display them with the GUI.

Here i how I would approach the problem:
You need many instances of 2D Matrix. Say you are varying 3 parameter: a, b, c.

```
a = 1, 2, 3, 4
b = 1, 2, 
c= 0.3, 0.5, 0.5
```

Then you have 4*2*3 images of the 2D Matrix that you need to fill offline.
Then you do:

```
Result := array(1...4, 1..2, 1..3, 1..40, 1..40)
```

This is assuming that your matrix 40x40. Then you have to create nested for loops (3 nests in this case) and fill your matrix.

When you move the GUI bars, you are changing the first 3 indices of the Result array and displaying data in the last 2.

Comment: Thanks for giving me direction for the data storage, But my main problem is the GUI part . what functions do I need to get the "nob/bar" part, or instant graphic update...etc.